# Symmetries of asymptotically AdS spacetimes

Tags: general-relativity, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

For asymptotically flat spacetimes, the group of symmetry tranformations of flat space, the Poincare group, is enhanced to the Bondi-Metzner-Sachs (BMS) group. Is there a similar enhancement for asymptotically anti-de Sitter spacetimes, from $SO(D-1,2)$ to something larger? Or is $SO(D-1,2)$ already the largest symmetry group in this case?

Comment: I have a suspicion that the Poincare -> BMS enhancement is analogous to the $SO(D-1,2)$ -> Weyl group enhancement. It'd be great if someone can confirm this.